# MS Access SQL statement

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

here's the situation, I work as the web dev for a local school district and my predecessor built a custom app to track kids' test scores. I'm no sql expert, so I defer to the masters!

I have the following tables built in MS Access:

- **Assessment** - this is the overarching category for the skills table (ie, math, reading, etc)
- **Skills** - these are the individual tests and are categorized by assessment ID
- **Mastery** - student scores; currently displays the skills ID

Below, are my tables as they are right now. The very last table is what I'd LIKE to have it be.

---

**Assessment Table**

```
asstID      asstName
1           Math
2           Reading
3           Literature
```

---

**Skills Table**

```
skillID     skillName   asstID
80          Vocabulary  3
81          Addition    1
82          Grammar     2
```

---

**Mastery Table**

```
masteryID   stuID       score       skillID
20          st001       89          82
21          st001       96          81
22          st001       100         80
23          st002       88          81
24          st002       74          80
25          st002       99          82
```

---

**Mastery Table** - What I *want* it to be.

```
masteryID   stuID       score       skillID     asstID
20          st001       89          82          2
21          st001       96          81          1
22          st001       100         80          3
23          st002       88          81          1
24          st002       74          80          3
25          st002       99          82          2
```

---

Basically, I have a couple thousand students that need to have the asstID added to the Mastery Table.

I'm looking for help creating a SQL statement I can put into MS Access that will display the asstID that corresponds to the skillID in the current table.

**ANY** help is appreciated.

*Please don't ask why we're using MS Access, that's just what he used when he built the app*

Comment: Down below, in the answers, I've added the ASP code that I used to update the table with the corresponding information, just in case anyone else runs into an issue like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT Mastery.masteryID, Mastery.stuID, Mastery.score, Mastery.skillID, Skills.asstID
FROM Mastery 
    INNER JOIN Skills 
        ON Mastery.skillID = Skills.skillID;
```

In the Query designer (QBE or Query-By-Example) grid, you would add the Mastery table and the Skills table and ensure that there was a relationship line between `Mastery.SkillID` and `Skills.SkillID`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll be looking at this in the morning when I'm back at work. I'll get back with you.

Comment: I can recreate my `tblMastery` via the Query Designer, so I *could* just copy the query results over to the new table, but I need a permanent solution for ongoing updates. Any ideas on how I might be able to query the `asstID` **inside** the `tblMastery` so that with every appended row, the `asstID` gets added? Or would that be something that'll need to get added in via the SQL inside the ASP code (in the app itself)?

Comment: I've changed the SQL in my `tblMastery.asstID` column to `SELECT tblSkills.asstID FROM tblMastery INNER JOIN tblSkills ON tblMastery.skillID=tblSkills.skillID;` and I'm getting a result in the dropdown box of the cell, but instead of matching the asstID with that row's skillID, it's giving me an dropdown box to select the asstID. And worse than that, the options listed are the results I'm needing to populate down through that column itself. Could a `WHERE` help here somehow?

Comment: @Max - RE: Updates. There is no means via data schema to accomplish this in Access outside of simply changing the schema. Instead, I would recommend one of two choices. Choice 1 is to encapsulate writing of values to the Mastery table such that it takes an asstID and writes it to the proper place. Choice 2 is to do something in a form event which writes this value.

Comment: @Max - RE: Change to SQL - The query I provided will obviously return all data from the join of Master to Skills. I.e., there is no filtering. If you want the skills for a specific asstID, then yes, you must adjust the query to include a Where clause that drops in the asstID you want. So something like `Select ... From Master Inner Join Skills On Mastery.SkillID = Skills.SkillID Where Skills.asstID = 12345`. Obviously instead of 12345 you would replace that value with the one you want. You may need to build this as a string and then set it to the drop lists' RecordSource.

Comment: You're SQL helped get me in the right direction. I ended up creating an ASP loop to update each of the rows with the correct asstID. Now, I'll have to go update all the assessment pages so that they input the asstID from now on. Thanks again for the help, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
SELECT mastery_table.masteryID, 
       mastery_table.stuID, 
       mastery_table.score, 
       mastery_table.skillID, 
       skills_table.asstID
  FROM mastery_table, skills_table
 WHERE mastery_table.skillID=skills_table.skillID
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll be looking at this in the morning when I'm back at work. I'll get back with you.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up using to update my 4k+ rows. Before running this, I created a new column in the DB itself named `asstID`.

Explanation:
 - loop through tblMastery & grab the value of tblMastery.skillID from each row
 - connect to tblSkills & grab the value of tblSkills.asstID where the tblSkills.skillID matches tblMastery.skillID
 - update tblMastery.asstID with the matching value from tblSkills.asstID

Hope this helps someone. :)

```
<%

set conn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Provider="Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
conn.Open "C:/database.mdb" 

set rs=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rs.open "SELECT tblMastery.Skill FROM tblMastery;", conn

  do until rs.eof
    skillID = rs.fields("Skill")

set rs1=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rs1.open "SELECT SkillID, Assesment FROM tblSkills WHERE SkillID='" & skillID & "';", conn

  asstID = rs1.fields("Assesment")

  sql = "UPDATE tblMastery SET asstID='" & asstID & "' WHERE Skill='" & skillID & "';"
  on error resume next
  conn.Execute(sql)

rs.movenext
loop

%>
```

Comment: It would be much better to use the join suggested by Thomas. This is pretty much against the rules of relational database design.

Comment: I don't have much experience in the area of database design. I asked for help w/in MS Access & Thomas did just that: the SQL provided by Thomas assisted me in retrieving the information I needed, I was unable to _update_ the table *through* Access the way I was hoping: as I said in my question, I am not very familiar with SQL; so I when back to what _am_ more familiar with & did what I could to figure it out.  If you know how to use Thomas' SQL statement to *update* the table needed, by all means please post it for future reference :)